# Prove claims about a monotone function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Let $f$ be a monotonically increasing function on $(a, b)$.
Prove that:

$\begin{array}{l}
 \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to x_0^ + } f(x) = {\inf _{x > {x_0}}}f(x) \\ 
 \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to x_0^ - } f(x) = {\sup _{x > {x_0}}}f(x) \\ 
 \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to x_0^ - } f(x) \le f(x) \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to x_0^ + } f(x) \\ 
 \end{array}$

I was guided to use the following lemma (proved at section a):

> If every monotone sub-sequence of $x_n$ converges to $x$ then the
> limit of $x_n$ is $x$.

From the fact that $f$ is monotonically increasing we can define:
$$L^- = \sup\{f(x)|a<x<x_0\}$$
$$L^+ = \sup\{f(x)|x_0 < x < b\}$$

And conclude that
$$L^- \le f(x_0) \le L^+$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from this point using the lemma.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: using point set topology?

Comment: I'm not familiar with topology (Calculus I).